# Optimizing re-labeling code

Tags: optimization, google-apps-script

Our company recently migrated from Exchange 2007 to Google Apps for Business. We have several shared mailboxes with a fairly complex and extensive folder structure and were asked to fully implement the labeling technique in these mailboxes (in order to optimize search).

e.g. Say, after migration, a conversation that used to be in MyCompany/Projects/2012/Q3/Approved Projects/StackOverflow (folder structure) now has the label MyCompany/Projects/2012/Q3/Approved Projects/StackOverflow.The intention here is that this conversation would have to be labeled with the labels MyCompany, Projects, 2012, Q3, Approved Projects, StackOverflow.

I have written a script that does exactly this (at least in my test environment). Problem is, according to what I've read, there are certain limitations involving the number of calls you are allowed to perform to the Google API. Also, script execution time is very, very poor.

I was wondering if there was a way to somehow perform operations client-side and send them to the google API in bulk. I have read about the Cache Services and was wondering if I was looking in the right direction.

This is my script:

```
function addLabels() {
  //Get all labels
  var allLabels = GmailApp.getUserLabels();

  for (var i = 0; i < allLabels.length; i++) {
    var label = allLabels[i];//label to get the threads from
    var threads = label.getThreads();  //threads assigned with label
    var labels = label.getName().split("/");//array of new label names

    //add the new labels to the specified threads only if there's a "/" in the label's name
    if(label.getName().indexOf("/") != null){
      for (var a = 0; a < labels.length; a++){
        trace("Adding label '" + labels[a] + "' to "+ threads.length +" threads in '"+ label.getName() + "'.");

        //create a new label with the specified name and add it to the threads
        //var newLabel = GmailApp.createLabel(labels[a]);//comment this line for test purposes
        //newLabel.addToThreads(threads);//comment this line for test purposes
      }
    }
  }
}
function trace(message){
  Logger.log(message);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run this script in stages. The first stage would be to determine all of the new labels that need to be created and the threads that should be assigned to them. The second  stage would be to create those labels. The final stage would be to assign those labels to the threads. If you are dealing with a large amount of email you may need to shard this work, keeping queues of work that is left to do, and using triggers to continue the processing.